# Logging query duration with EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, logging, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

In an attempt to log time spent on SQL Server queries in an ASP.NET Core web application I've been using the following code, having subscribed to all `DiagnosticListeners` in some middleware and using the `Observable` below.

I'm not sure this is the most optimal solution in terms of performance and wondered if there was a better way using the ASP.NET Core Logging API by capturing detailed logging objects directly from EFCore?  Ideally I want to keep a total of the duration of all queries performed through a request and have the total in milliseconds at the end of a request which the Middleware can use.

```
public class QueryTimingObserver : IObserver<DiagnosticListener>
{
    private readonly List<IDisposable> subscriptions = new List<IDisposable>();
    private readonly AsyncLocal<Stopwatch> stopwatch = new AsyncLocal<Stopwatch>();
    private double milliseconds = 0;

    void IObserver<DiagnosticListener>.OnNext(DiagnosticListener diagnosticListener)
    {
        if (diagnosticListener.Name == "SqlClientDiagnosticListener")
        {
            IDisposable subscription = diagnosticListener.SubscribeWithAdapter(this);
            subscriptions.Add(subscription);
        }
    }

    void IObserver<DiagnosticListener>.OnError(Exception error)
    {
    }

    void IObserver<DiagnosticListener>.OnCompleted()
    {
        subscriptions.ForEach(x => x.Dispose());
        subscriptions.Clear();
    }

    [DiagnosticName("System.Data.SqlClient.WriteCommandBefore")]
    public void OnCommandBefore()
    {
        stopwatch.Value = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }

    [DiagnosticName("System.Data.SqlClient.WriteCommandAfter")]
    public void OnCommandAfter(DbCommand command)
    {
        stopwatch.Value.Stop();
        milliseconds += stopwatch.Value.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    public double Milliseconds
    {
        get
        {
            return milliseconds;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sharing what I do in my project.

1. Create ApiRequest object for each incoming request.
2. Gather essential information from request like ip address, user agent,
   user id, referrer, UriPath, Search Type etc.
3. Now I can get reference to ApiRequest object in my controller/service layer and
   start/stop timer and calculate time for each steps (db
   calls)
4. Save ApiRequest object to preferred logging database
   before giving response.

ApiRequest class:

```
public class ApiRequest : IDisposable
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    // public string RequestId { get; set; }
    public string ClientSessionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequestStartTime { get; set; }
    public string LogLevel { get; set; }
    public string AccessProfile { get; set; }
    public string ApiClientIpAddress { get; set; }
    public GeoData ApiClientGeoData { get; set; }
    public string OriginatingIpAddress { get; set; }
    public GeoData OriginatingGeoData { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsError { get; set; }
    // public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public ConcurrentBag<string> Errors { get; set; }
    public ConcurrentBag<string> Warnings { get; set; }
    public long TotalExecutionTimeInMs { get; set; }
    public long? ResponseSizeInBytes { get; set; }
    public long TotalMySqlSpCalls { get; set; }
    public long DbConnectionTimeInMs { get; set; }
    public long DbCallTimeInMs { get; set; }
    public long OverheadTimeInMs { get; set; }
    public string UriHost { get; set; }
    public string UriPath { get; set; }
    public string SearchRequest { get; set; }
    public string Referrer { get; set; }
    public string UserAgent { get; set; }
    public string SearchType { get; set; }
    public ConcurrentQueue<RequestExecutionStatistics> ExecutionHistory { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [BsonIgnore]
    public Stopwatch Timer { get; set; }

    public ApiRequest(Stopwatch stopwatch)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        // RequestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Timer = stopwatch;
        RequestStartTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(Timer.Elapsed);
        ExecutionHistory = new ConcurrentQueue<RequestExecutionStatistics>();
        ExecutionHistory.Enqueue(new RequestExecutionStatistics
        {
            Description = "HTTP Request Start",
            Status = RequestExecutionStatus.Started,
            Index = 1,
            StartTime = Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds,
            ExecutionTimeInMs = 0
        });
        Errors = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
        Warnings = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
    }

    public Task AddExecutionTimeStats(string description, RequestExecutionStatus status, long startTime, long executionTimeInMs)
    {
        int count = ExecutionHistory.Count;

        return Task.Run(() =>
            ExecutionHistory.Enqueue(new RequestExecutionStatistics
            {
                Description = description,
                Status = status,
                Index = count + 1,
                StartTime = startTime,
                ExecutionTimeInMs = executionTimeInMs
            }));
    }

    public Task UpdateExecutionTimeStats(string description, long executionTimeInMs)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var stats = ExecutionHistory.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Description.ToLower() == description.ToLower());
            if (stats != null) stats.ExecutionTimeInMs = executionTimeInMs;
        });
    }

    #region IDisposable implementation

    private bool _disposed;

    // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed) { return; }

        if (disposing)
        {
            // Free managed objects here.
            Timer.Stop(); // Probably doesn't matter, but anyways...
        }

        // Free any unmanaged objects here.


        // Mark this object as disposed.
        _disposed = true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Sample Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize(Policy = Constants.Policies.CanAccessSampleSearch)]
public class SampleSearchController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;
    private readonly ISampleSearchService _sampleService;

    public SampleSearchController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings, ISampleSearchService sampleSearchService)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
        _sampleService = sampleSearchService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<Response> PostAsync([FromBody]PersonRequest request)
    {
        var apiRequest = HttpContext.Items[Constants.CacheKeys.SampleApiRequest] as ApiRequest;
        await apiRequest.AddExecutionTimeStats("Sample Search Controller", RequestExecutionStatus.Started,
            apiRequest.Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds, 0);

        var result = new Response();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            apiRequest.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            apiRequest.IsError = true;

            foreach (var modelState in ModelState.Values)
            {
                foreach (var error in modelState.Errors)
                {
                    apiRequest.Errors.Add(error.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = await _sampleService.Search(request);
        }

        await apiRequest.AddExecutionTimeStats("Sample Search Controller", RequestExecutionStatus.Complted, 0,
            apiRequest.Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Sample Service:

```
public class SampleSearchService : ISampleSearchService
{
    #region Variables

    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;
    private readonly IStateService _stateService;
    private readonly IDistrictService _districtService;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    #endregion Variables

    public SampleSearchService(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings, IStateService stateService,
        IDistrictService districtService, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
        _stateService = stateService;
        _districtService = districtService;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task<Response> Search(PersonRequest request)
    {
        var apiRequest =
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items[Constants.CacheKeys.SampleApiRequest] as ApiRequest;

        await apiRequest.AddExecutionTimeStats("Sample Search Service", RequestExecutionStatus.Started,
            apiRequest.Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds, 0);

        var response = new Response();

        using (var db = new ApplicationDb(_appSettings.ConnectionStrings.MyContext))
        {
            var dbConnectionStartTime = apiRequest.Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            await db.Connection.OpenAsync();
            apiRequest.DbConnectionTimeInMs = apiRequest.Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds - dbConnectionStartTime;

            await apiRequest.AddExecutionTimeStats("DB Connection", RequestExecutionStatus.Complted,
                dbConnectionStartTime, apiRequest.DbConnectionTimeInMs);

            using (var command = db.Command(_appSettings.StoredProcedures.GetSampleByCriteria,
                _appSettings.Timeouts.GetSampleByCriteriaTimeout, CommandType.StoredProcedure, db.Connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "p_Id",
                    DbType = DbType.Int64,
                    Value = request.Id
                });                    

                try
                {
                    await apiRequest.AddExecutionTimeStats("Sample DB Call", RequestExecutionStatus.Started,
                        apiRequest.Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds, 0);

                    response = await ReadAllAsync(await command.ExecuteReaderAsync());

                    await apiRequest.AddExecutionTimeStats("Sample DB Call", RequestExecutionStatus.Complted, 0,
                        apiRequest.Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    apiRequest.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    apiRequest.IsError = true;
                    apiRequest.Errors.Add(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        apiRequest.SearchRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
        await apiRequest.AddExecutionTimeStats("Sample Search Service", RequestExecutionStatus.Complted, 0,
            apiRequest.Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        return response;
    }

    private async Task<Response> ReadAllAsync(DbDataReader reader)
    {
        var SampleResponse = new Response();

        using (reader)
        {
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                SampleResponse.AvailableCount = Convert.ToInt32(await reader.GetFieldValueAsync<long>(0));

                if (reader.NextResult())
                {
                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        var SampleRecord = new Record()
                        {                                
                            District = !await reader.IsDBNullAsync(1) ? await reader.GetFieldValueAsync<string>(6) : null,
                            State = !await reader.IsDBNullAsync(2) ? await reader.GetFieldValueAsync<string>(7) : null
                        };

                        SampleResponse.Records.Add(SampleRecord);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return SampleResponse;
    }
}
```

ApiRequestsMiddleware:

```
public class ApiRequestsMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IApiRequestService _apiRequestService;

    public ApiRequestsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IApiRequestService apiRequestService)
    {
        _next = next;
        _apiRequestService = apiRequestService;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var accessProfileName = context.User.Claims != null && context.User.Claims.Any()
            ? context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value
            : null;

        try
        {
            var request = new ApiRequest(stopwatch)
            {
                AccessProfile = accessProfileName,
                ClientSessionId = ContextHelper.GetHeadersValue(context, Constants.Headers.ClientSessionId),
                ApiClientIpAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()
            };

            var originatingIpAddress = ContextHelper.GetHeadersValue(context, Constants.Headers.OriginatingIpAddress);
            request.OriginatingIpAddress = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(originatingIpAddress)
                ? originatingIpAddress
                : context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();

            request.UriHost = context.Request.Host.ToString();
            request.UriPath = context.Request.Path;

            var referrer = ContextHelper.GetHeadersValue(context, Constants.Headers.Referrer);
            request.Referrer = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(referrer) ? referrer : null;

            var userAgent = ContextHelper.GetHeadersValue(context, Constants.Headers.UserAgent);
            request.UserAgent = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userAgent) ? userAgent : null;

            request.SearchType = SearchHelper.GetSearchType(request.UriPath).ToString();

            context.Items.Add(Constants.CacheKeys.SampleApiRequest, request);

            await _next(context);
            stopwatch.Stop();

            request.StatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode;
            request.LogLevel = LogLevel.Information.ToString();
            request.TotalExecutionTimeInMs = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            if (request.IsError)
                request.LogLevel = LogLevel.Error.ToString();

            if (_apiRequestService != null)
                Task.Run(() => _apiRequestService.Create(request));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public static class ApiRequestsMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseApiRequests(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<ApiRequestsMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

ApiRequestService (to insert log entry to db):

```
public class ApiRequestService : IApiRequestService
{
    private readonly IMongoDbContext _context;
    private readonly IIpLocatorService _ipLocatorService;

    public ApiRequestService(IMongoDbContext context, IIpLocatorService ipLocatorService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _ipLocatorService = ipLocatorService;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<ApiRequest>> Get()
    {
        return await _context.ApiRequests.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<ApiRequest> Get(string id)
    {
        var filter = Builders<ApiRequest>.Filter.Eq("Id", id);

        try
        {
            return await _context.ApiRequests.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public async Task Create(ApiRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            request.OriginatingGeoData = null; // await _ipLocatorService.Get(request.OriginatingIpAddress);

            var finalHistory = new ConcurrentQueue<RequestExecutionStatistics>();

            foreach (var history in request.ExecutionHistory.ToList())
            {
                if (history.Status == RequestExecutionStatus.Started)
                {
                    var findPartner = request.ExecutionHistory.FirstOrDefault(e =>
                        e.Description.ToLower() == history.Description.ToLower() &&
                        e.Status == RequestExecutionStatus.Complted);

                    if (findPartner != null)
                    {
                        var temp = history.Clone();
                        temp.Status = RequestExecutionStatus.Complted;
                        temp.ExecutionTimeInMs = findPartner.ExecutionTimeInMs - history.StartTime;
                        finalHistory.Enqueue(temp);
                    }
                    else
                        finalHistory.Enqueue(history);
                }
                else if (history.Status == RequestExecutionStatus.Complted)
                {
                    var findPartner = request.ExecutionHistory.FirstOrDefault(e =>
                        e.Description.ToLower() == history.Description.ToLower() &&
                        e.Status == RequestExecutionStatus.Started);

                    if (findPartner == null)
                        finalHistory.Enqueue(history);
                }
            }

            request.ExecutionHistory = finalHistory;
            request.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            request.CreatedBy = Environment.MachineName;
            await _context.ApiRequests.InsertOneAsync(request);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Register in Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        // Other code        

        app.UseApiRequests();
        app.UseResponseWrapper();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Sample log output:

```
{
"_id" : "75a90cc9-5d80-4eb8-aae1-70a3611fe8ff",
"RequestId" : "98be1d85-9941-4a17-a73a-5f0a38bd7703",
"ClientSessionId" : null,
"RequestStartTime" : ISODate("2019-09-11T15:22:05.802-07:00"),
"LogLevel" : "Information",
"AccessProfile" : "Sample",
"ApiClientIpAddress" : "0.0.0.0",
"ApiClientGeoData" : null,
"OriginatingIpAddress" : "0.0.0.0",
"OriginatingGeoData" : null,
"StatusCode" : 200,
"IsError" : false,
"Errors" : [],
"Warnings" : [],
"TotalExecutionTimeInMs" : NumberLong(115),
"ResponseSizeInBytes" : NumberLong(0),
"TotalMySqlSpCalss" : NumberLong(0),
"DbConnectionTimeInMs" : NumberLong(3),
"DbCallTimeInMs" : NumberLong(0),
"OverheadTimeInMs" : NumberLong(0),
"UriHost" : "www.sampleapi.com",
"UriPath" : "/api/Samples",
"SearchRequest" : null,
"Referrer" : null,
"UserAgent" : null,
"SearchType" : "Sample",
"ExecutionHistory" : [ 
    {
        "Description" : "HTTP Request Start",
        "Index" : 1,
        "StartTime" : NumberLong(0),
        "ExecutionTimeInMs" : NumberLong(0)
    }, 
    {
        "Description" : "Sample Search Controller",
        "Index" : 2,
        "StartTime" : NumberLong(0),
        "ExecutionTimeInMs" : NumberLong(115)
    }, 
    {
        "Description" : "Sample Search Service",
        "Index" : 3,
        "StartTime" : NumberLong(0),
        "ExecutionTimeInMs" : NumberLong(115)
    }, 
    {
        "Description" : "DB Connection",
        "Index" : 4,
        "StartTime" : NumberLong(0),
        "ExecutionTimeInMs" : NumberLong(3)
    }, 
    {
        "Description" : "Sample DB Call",
        "Index" : 5,
        "StartTime" : NumberLong(3),
        "ExecutionTimeInMs" : NumberLong(112)
    }
],
"CreatedDate" : ISODate("2019-09-11T15:22:05.918-07:00"),
"CreatedBy" : "Server"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class QueryInterceptor
    {
        private readonly ILogger<QueryInterceptor> _logger;
        private string _query;
        private DateTimeOffset _startTime;
        public QueryInterceptor(ILogger<QueryInterceptor> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [DiagnosticName("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command.CommandExecuting")]
        public void OnCommandExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, Guid commandId, Guid connectionId, bool async, DateTimeOffset startTime)
        {
            _query = command.CommandText;
            _startTime = startTime;
        }

        [DiagnosticName("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command.CommandExecuted")]
        public void OnCommandExecuted(object result, bool async)
        {
            var endTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            var queryTiming = (endTime - _startTime).TotalSeconds;
            _logger.LogInformation("\n" + "Executes " + "\n" + _query + "\n" + "in " + queryTiming + " seconds\n");
        }

        [DiagnosticName("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command.CommandError")]
        public void OnCommandError(Exception exception, bool async)
        {
            _logger.LogError(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

and in Program.cs

```
var loggerQueryInterceptor = services.GetService<ILogger<QueryInterceptor>>();
var listener = context.GetService<DiagnosticSource>();
(listener as DiagnosticListener).SubscribeWithAdapter(new QueryInterceptor(loggerQueryInterceptor));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to measure performance, but when it comes to timing queries, I start with database server tools like SQL Profiler. In the case of SQL Server, the SQL Server Profiler and the SQL Server Management Studio tools provide endless amounts of detail.

Now, I can't specifically comment on your code, but I can maybe give you some suggestions worth considering. If I want to log query execution time in code then I usually do one of two things.

1) The tried and tested stopwatch never fails. Like you're doing.

2) Now, my most favorite tool. If I can, I use [MiniProfiler](https://miniprofiler.com/) in my projects. It came out of Stack Exchange, the people who run this very website where we're discussing profiling now. It shows you the SQL queries and warns you about common mistakes. You can use it with EF Core and it has a beautiful widget that you can easily integrate into a page on your website to view what is happening at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Query performance should be done at two levels, timing the controller/service actions, and profiling at the database level. Performance issues crop up for a number of reasons, and might be detected only at the controller, or at the database, or both. Recording performance metrics at the code level should always be configurable to be able to turn it off and on easily because any performance capture represents a performance hit, plus resource space needed to record the results.

At the risk of being a bit off-topic I've outlined the typical performance pitfalls I come across and how I measure/detect them. The purpose would just be to outline why SQL-side profiling can be valuable along-side code-based timers to detect potential performance issues, as well as identify steps to resolve them.

1. Rogue lazy load calls. Detected by SQL profiling. Web requests query data where the initial query completes fast, the web request appears to end fast in a debugger, but the client doesn't receive a response for some time. After the initial query(ies) and the request completes, a number of "by ID" queries are tracked by the profiler. These are lazy load calls tripped by a serializer. Cause: Anti-pattern of passing entities to view/consumer. Solution: Use projection to fill view models.
2. Expensive queries. Detected by code timers and SQL profiling. These queries take a significant amount of time to run which is detectable by debugging. These queries also show a detectable execution time in profiler results. Solutions range from checking the executed query for execution plan improvements, (missing/improvable indexes) to determining if the query can be simplified or broken up in code.
3. Intermittently slow queries. Detected by code timers and SQL profiling. These can be picked up ahead of time by inspecting profiling results. The tell-tale signs are queries that involve significantly large row touch counts. When running in low-load scenarios these queries can have very reasonable execution times. In higher-load times the execution times can spike up dramatically. Queries touching a lot of rows risk tying each other up with row locks needed to avoid dirty reads. Locks result in delays, and potential deadlocks. Solutions include: Refining queries to only pull back the data they need to leverage indexes better, and for expansive queries for reports and searches, consider hitting read-only replicas in larger systems.
4. EF "isms". Detected by code timers, not profiling. Some EF queries can just get a bit weird when projecting entity graphs. The underlying queries run fast, and spawns no additional queries, but the EF query sits and churns before returning. Sometimes these can result from complex Linq expressions that result in a reasonable looking query, but it just seems to sit there. Sometimes the cause can be fairly obvious, such as a long-lived DbContext that ends up tracking a good chunk of the entire database. Other times the solutions need to be analysed a case-by-case basis. They usually involve using/altering projection to simplify the data coming back from EF, or breaking up queries into simpler pieces, even if it results in two queries instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

This a demo and have no test in production

Will log query with great than 10s

```cs
public class SlowQueryLogger : RelationalCommandDiagnosticsLogger
{
    public SlowQueryLogger(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ILoggingOptions loggingOptions, DiagnosticSource diagnosticSource, LoggingDefinitions loggingDefinitions, IDbContextLogger contextLogger, IDbContextOptions contextOptions, IInterceptors? interceptors = null) : base(loggerFactory, loggingOptions, diagnosticSource, loggingDefinitions, contextLogger, contextOptions, interceptors)
    {
    }

    public override ValueTask<DbDataReader> CommandReaderExecutedAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommand command, DbContext? context, Guid commandId, Guid connectionId, DbDataReader methodResult, DateTimeOffset startTime, TimeSpan duration, CommandSource commandSource, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (duration > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
        {
#pragma warning disable EF1001 // Internal EF Core API usage.
            ((RelationalLoggingDefinitions)Definitions).LogExecutedCommand =
     new EventDefinition<string, string, CommandType, int, string, string>(
         Options,
         RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted,
         LogLevel.Warning,
         "RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted",
         (LogLevel level) =>
         LoggerMessage.Define<string, string, CommandType, int, string, string>(level,
         RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted,
         "Executed DbCommand ({elapsed}ms) [Parameters=[{parameters}], CommandType='{commandType}', CommandTimeout='{commandTimeout}']{newLine}{commandText}"));
        }
        else
        {
            ((RelationalLoggingDefinitions)Definitions).LogExecutedCommand =
new EventDefinition<string, string, CommandType, int, string, string>(
Options,
RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted,
LogLevel.Information,
"RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted",
(LogLevel level) =>
LoggerMessage.Define<string, string, CommandType, int, string, string>(level,
RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted,
"Executed DbCommand ({elapsed}ms) [Parameters=[{parameters}], CommandType='{commandType}', CommandTimeout='{commandTimeout}']{newLine}{commandText}"));
        }
        return base.CommandReaderExecutedAsync(connection, command, context, commandId, connectionId, methodResult, startTime, duration, commandSource, cancellationToken);
#pragma warning restore EF1001 // Internal EF Core API usage.
    }
}
```

In program.cs

```cs
services.AddDbContextPool<ContextBase>((Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>)(option =>
{
xxxx...
    option.ReplaceService<IRelationalCommandDiagnosticsLogger, SlowQueryLogger>();
}));
```